# How to identify any one IP is active in sub net mash (range) or non of the IP

Tags: python, linux, network-programming, ip, subnet

I have a subnet and i want to know is there any ip in that range is active or not. In that range any one IP can able to ping and  return the value, if no IP is pingable it has to return none.

e.g: 10.116.126.0/24

I tried but in both scenarios it returning TRUE.

Comment: Devices can be active but configured to not reply to a ping request. In any case, you will need to try each individually; you cannot ping a range.

Comment: Is there any way to identify to know at least one IP in subnet is active?

Comment: Without looping every IP in subnet range to check active or not. It has to return any one IP is active, My problem is looping every IP it takes lot of time. I have to check many subnets at a time.